# Force Maven compiler plugin to use generated sources instead of duplicate existing classes

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, code-generation, maven-plugin

I'm working on a plugin for Maven. I need to replace certain lines of code (actually, one annotation) in a source Java file. Of course, I'm not going to edit the original file so I'm creating a new one in my plugin. But I can't make Maven use my generated source instead of the original one. I've tried to exclude a file when from compilation but it excludes the generated one. Without exclusion I'm getting duplicate class error while compiling the project.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What kind of annotation are you writing a plugin for ?

Comment: @khmarbaise One of the goals is to replace Spring `@Component` annotation with `@Configurable`

Comment: Sounds to me a little bit weird...Why not using `@Configurable` instead of `@Component`? Apart from that your plugin should generate to `target/generated-sources` and furthermore set the `getProject().addCompileSourceRoot( );` to get the correct location of your sources being added to the folders which will be used for compiling and of course you need to check if your plugin runs at the correct phase...

Comment: @khmarbaise This plugin will not replace the annotation only:) It will configure a project in order not to burden a developer with manual work. Actually, there is the build-helper-maven-plugin plugin that helps to add generated source to those being processed. The problem is that there is no way to replace the original file with the one generated. I have to use the same class name. So as I see I have to use bytecode manipulation to replace the annotation.

Comment: The build-helper-maven-plugin is the wrong way...cause a plugin should handle all that without any supplemental configuration of the user...You simply need to locate the original java file somewhere else than `src/main/java`something like `src/main/xxx` and your plugin will pick it up and generate the correct class into `target/generated-sources/..` and add it to the compileSourceRoot....

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you, it is an interesting idea but I'm writing the plugin assuming a developer will have standard layout. I won't be able to change it. I've achieved the similar goal changing bytecode.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm suggesting cause standard layout contains hand written classes and the supplemental folder contains a special template class which is later used generated the real code...which is ok for a special plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess you should proceed and answer the question but we should warn other guys not to use the approach with generating sources in this case. I will mark it as right then.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, english is not my native language.
I was able to get Maven use my generated source instead of the original one.

In my project i have class with base configuration. And directory with configurations for clients.
During maven build i need to replace base configuration class with client one. I'm achived this with two plugins:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <!-- Copy source file from another directory -->
            <directory>${project.basedir}/../configs/${client-directory}</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/com/package</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>ClientConfig.java</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- Exclude base config -->
                    <exclude>com/package/ClientConfig.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <!-- Add client config -->
                    <arg>-sourcepath</arg>
                    <arg>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In includes and excludes tags of maven-compiler-plugin you can't use path for java file. You should use package and class name or pattern. Because of this you can't add java file from generated-sources to compilation with this tags.

You can try to use somethink like this.